# VIbrato (pitch variation) function

Tags: audio, frequency, c, c++

I'm looking for an algorithm for [Vibrato audio effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrato) for a cross-platform C++ program of audio processing. Now I use the realization from [Chaotic-DAW sources](https://github.com/dliganov/Chaotic-DAW/blob/master/rosic/effects/rosic_Vibrato.h). The problem is that Chaotic-DAW has a ***huge*** class hierarchy, and:
 1. I don't want to use such a huge library
 2. I cannot use it on Mac OS X ([cannot compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699727/qt-clang-portaudio-what-does-those-errors-mean?))
 3. I will not be able to port the program to a microcontroller.

The necessary Vibrato parameters: delay, depth, period (cycle length).

[Related topic on Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/looking-for-audio-processing-library).

**Update.** *I have tried to isolate the Vibrato class, but the hierarchy is so large that it's impossible.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and asking questions, I have written my own realization for the vibrato effect: **https://github.com/Bershov/Vibrato-effect**. The code is not hard for understanding and works fine. In fact, the vibrato is a kind of [frequency modulation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) Its key concepts: variable delay, low-frequency oscillation and intelpolation.